# Fixing FPS with Centiseconds

Tags: c, pthreads, frame-rate

I'm trying to fix a thread to update the screen at 25 FPS, but the guides I've looked needs milliseconds. However, my timer functions does not return the time elapsed in milliseconds but centiseconds(for example returns 100 for 1s, 1246 for 12 seconds and 460 milliseconds). How should I do this with centiseconds?

Comment: Lucky for you, 1/25 is 40 milliseconds, which is 4 centiseconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert milliseconds to centiseconds or vice-versa:

10 millisecond = 1 centiseconds

Therefore,

x centiseconds = (10 * x) milliseconds.

But there is no need to here. Let's look at 25 FPS in centiseconds:

25 FPS = 1 Frame per (1/25) seconds
25 FPS = 1 Frame per (1/25)*(100) centiseconds

**25 FPS = 1 Frame per 4 centiseconds**

Hope this helps.